# Sending data from desktop app to web app

Tags: java, mysql, apache, http

I have been looking for an answer since an long time now and i gte answer that i Should use RestApi or i should try it with this and that code but now i want to aks what is the easiest and securest way to send data from and desktop app to an web app and then get the web apps respond and giving it back to the desktop app. I used the direct way with hardcoding the passwords and all the database things so the desktop app will directly connect to the Database but that isn't secure at all. If you could provide me with a link or with the code i would help me more then just giving hints and playing hide and seek with me :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: A "WebAPI" or "Restful" API which exchanges data in XML or JSON format is probably your best choice. All communications over the wire should be done through https (SSL) and, depending on the data, you might also consider encrypting the data itself (maybe through the exchange of public keys), but that depends on "how" secure you want it.

Comment: We're a bunch of programmers of various levels; if you're one of us, we'd like to help. If you're not one of us, you might get to feel like we're playing hide-and-seek, when really, we're providing reasonable programmer answers (like MadProgrammer's above). It's general, but it accurately gives you programmer-level advice. It helps when you include some code, too.

Comment: Okay Thanks Guys laready helped me alot all of you

Answer (score 0):

You could use Web Services like , RESTful or WSDL. I think you could start it from WSDL. Othewise you could use encryption methods your own.

Please refer following links to get some idea

[Web Service Introduction](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/821-0236/ghyto/index.html